# Heroku error:Name must start with a letter and can only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes

Tags: heroku, deployment, rename

I have just deployed php project on Heroku.
And receive app name :aqueous-thicket-59864
Now I want to change it "dynamic_datatable_ajax"
so I tryed these cmd but they don't work.

```
heroku apps:rename dynamic_datatable_ajax
heroku apps:rename dynamic_datatable_ajax --app aqueous-thicket-59864

git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a dynamic_datatable_ajax
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want is:

```
heroku apps:rename dynamic-datatable-ajax --app aqueous-thicket-59864
```

An underscore (what you were using) is invalid.